# If a vector $\vec a$ is not in $\operatorname{Span}(\vec b,\vec c)$, is $\operatorname{Span}(\vec a, \vec b, \vec c) = \Bbb R^3$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec c$, $\vec d$ all different vectors.

I heard that, if $\vec a\not\in \operatorname{Span}(\vec b)$ is true, $\operatorname{Span}(\vec a,\vec b) = \Bbb{R}^2$.

What I am curious about is this.

If $\vec a \not\in \operatorname{Span}(\vec b,\vec c)$ is true, is $\operatorname{Span}(\vec a, \vec b, \vec c) = \Bbb{R}^3$ true?

Then, if $\vec a\not\in \operatorname{Span}(\vec b,\vec c, \vec d)$ is true, is $\operatorname{Span}(\vec a, \vec b, \vec c, \vec d) = \Bbb{R}^4$ true, and so on?

Comment: No.  Suppose $\vec b = \vec c$.

Comment: Note:  your first claim isn't strictly true either, if  $\vec b = \vec 0$ then it is false.  You need to exclude $\vec 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** true.

If for instance $\mathrm{Span}(\vec b,\vec c)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ of dimension $1$ (which is the case if $\vec b=\vec c$ or $\vec c=3\vec b$ or...), then $\mathrm{Span}(\vec a,\vec b,\vec c)$ can not have a dimension geater than $2$ so it can't be all $\mathbb R^3$.

It is true if you assume that $\mathrm{Span}(\vec b,\vec c)$ has dimension $2$.

*Remark: The first claim is also not true, you need to assume that $\mathrm{Span}(\vec b)$ has dimension $1$ (which is the case if $\vec b\ne \vec 0$).*

Comment: ah, okay. i understand why. does the converse work?

Comment: @keist99 Yes, the converse is true.